# Bypass the minimum waiting time on Imacros

Tags: javascript, timeout, captcha, imacros, feedback

Hi guys I was wondering if it's possible to bypass the waiting time this site wants me to wait and autofill a captcha code.

I was thinking about using iMacros to do multiple searches for me on the same site and then also filling in a random captha code and then after that pressing enter to see all the information about regarding my search and then extract the info. The problem is that the site won't let me do a new search if I don't wait for "x" Seconds..

I want to do 100.000 searches so I would want to skip the waiting period.. 
and i would be thankfull for any help becuse this kind of scripting is to hard for me to manage by myself..

Thankfull for all feedback and help.

Comment: Or is this not even possible? Looks hard.. I'm not getting any feedback

Comment: Go in settings and change default waiting time.

Comment: the problem is not with imacros.. it's thats the page im visiting is making me to wait "x" secunds before being able to do a new search, i can make new search after 1 secund but it says that i have to go back to the original page where i did the search and wait a little bit between my searches.. do u get it?

Comment: No but use BACK command as many times as you need.

Comment: so i cant bypass the requaired waiting time?

Answer (score 0):

Locate the source of the blocking.
If the website blocks multiple tries because of your IP use proxy and change ip between each search:

```
PROXY ADDRESS=proxy_URL:port [BYPASS=page_name]
```

you can buy proxy addresses from HMAPRO.

If they use cookies you can use `CLEAR` command to delete all web browser saved info.

If it is by username you can create multiple accounts using iMacros.